# Visual Studio 2017 Community Live Share Co-Debug not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build, console-application, visual-studio-liveshare

So recently I started using **Live Share** extension for Visual Studio 2017 Community with friend. I read about it on Microsoft page ([Link Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/use/vs)) and I do not understand why **Co-Debugging** is not working or in other words why **Co-BuildApp** is not working.

Everything is set up including **Shared Server** which is not working too. First thing to know is , that we are programming *Console Application* so I want to know how he can *Build & Run* code so he can see application window too. Only thing he can see on screen is this : [Friend's view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwHNT.png)

Any ideas ?